# Marketing Cloud Test Data Creation for SF Sandbox

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Hi I need to create Marketing Cloud test data in my Sandbox, but when I try to create test data for EmailSends, I get an error:

```
List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Error is in expression '{!initialize}' in component <apex:page> in page et4ae5:sendetemail: (et4ae5)
An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been notified. (et4ae5)
```

How do I generally create test data for the Marketing Cloud in Salesforce, and when I create a Partial Copy Sandbox, will also Marketing Cloud test data be copied via template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019XItQAM#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_SEARCH_RESULT&id=90630000000Zho3AAC in order to generate testing data, you need to connect the sandbox to the Marketing Cloud via the Connector. You can point the Sandbox to one Business Unit for testing and point your production to another Business Unit within the same Marketing Cloud account.

I think this should help creating Marketing Cloud data in the Sandbox.